# get default name or id input from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi people as all know rails by default put ids and names id=model_attribute and name=model[attribute].

My question is How I can get the default id or name from a Model o with I18n?

For example User.human_attribute_name 'password' give the Password label, well how i do to put 
User.give_me_the_id_or_name 'password' and give 'user[password]' or 'user_password'

Thinks at advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source. http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb
and build your own construction in your model class if you really want to. :)

```
def self.give_me_the_id_or_name(method)
  result = "#{self.model_name.param_key}[#{method.to_s.sub(/\?$/,"")}]"
  result.instance_eval do
    def id
      self.gsub(/\]\[|[^-a-zA-Z0-9:.]/, "_").sub(/_$/, "")
    end
  end
  result
end

User.give_me_the_id_or_name(:password) ===>  "user[password]"
User.give_me_the_id_or_name(:password).id ===> "user_password"
```

But I'm actually don't understand what you mean about I18n? These names used by default as tags titles when you rendering the model into tempate.